# Saving weighted survey as data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to analyze a survey which was analyzed in the past with the SPSS software. The survey has a weight variable.

In SPSS it's easy to weight by variable (with the 'weight by' function) But I have problems while tring to do so with R.

I used the Survay package to include the weight variable. I will show here a more simple example:

```
    Data <- data.frame(
    X =c(1,4,6,4,1,7,3,2,2),
    Y = c(6,5,9,9,43,65,45,67,90),
    weight=c(0.1,1.2,4,0,0,5,0.65,1,0)
    )
    summary(Data )
```

```
      X               Y             weight     
 Min.   :1.000   Min.   : 5.00   Min.   :0.000
 1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.: 9.00   1st Qu.:0.000
 Median :3.000   Median :43.00   Median :0.650
 Mean   :3.333   Mean   :37.67   Mean   :1.328
 3rd Qu.:4.000   3rd Qu.:65.00   3rd Qu.:1.200
 Max.   :7.000   Max.   :90.00   Max.   :5.000
```

```
    library(survey)
    dat_weight=svydesign(ids = ~1, data = Data , weights = Data $weight)
```

Now I would like to save this object (dat_weight) as a simple data frame and use it for other analyses (such as PCA, CA, and so on).

Can it be done?

Comment: What are `dat1` and `dat_weight` like? Maybe you should use `str` function to have a look.

Comment: Can you make this example reproducible? You are more likely to get  help that way. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Have you tried the `weighted.mean` base function? Also, I'm not really sure what you're actually trying to do. Can you just `temp <- summary(dat_weight)`

Comment: I want to perform PCA analysis on this data frame, but I don't know how to weight the observations by the variable "weight" and than save this as data frame. the function svydesign creates a "survey.design" class and can't be tranform to a data frame

Comment: The weights were already calculated, why use the `survey` package?

Comment: The use of weights in PCA does not appear to be exactly straightforward: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113485/weighted-principal-components-analysis

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I found a surprisingly easy solution. You can use `save()` function to save a R object to a specific file with extension `.RData`. Once you have done that, you can read back the object with `load()` function without assigning it to anything because it will assign to its original name when you saved.

See the following example:

```
Data <- data.frame(
    X =c(1,4,6,4,1,7,3,2,2),
    Y = c(6,5,9,9,43,65,45,67,90),
    weight=c(0.1,1.2,4,0,0,5,0.65,1,0)
)
dat_weight <- survey::svydesign(ids = ~1, data = Data, weights = Data$weight)
save(dat_weight, file = "~/weighted_data.RData")

# clean environment
rm(list = ls())
load("~/weighted_data.RData")
```

Next time you don't have to apply weights on your dataset and instead directly dive into analysis.